# create procedure in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, procedure

why it does not work ?
i run this in oracle .
i want to create aprocedure like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ME( X in NUMBER )IS  
declare 
num1 number;
BEGIN  
num1:=1;
insert into a (year) values(7);    
END;
```

this is the error:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:
          begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
           current cursor delete
          exists prior external language
          The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.
7/5     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
          ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
          null pragma raise return select update while with
           
           << continue close current delete fetch lock
          insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
          merge pipe purge

Answer (score 6):

`DECLARE` is only used in anonymous PL/SQL blocks and nested PL/SQL blocks.  You wouldn't use it when you're declaring a procedure.  Assuming the table `A` exists with a column `YEAR`, something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ME( X in NUMBER )
IS  
  num1 number;
BEGIN  
  num1:=1;
  insert into a (year) values(7);    
END;
```

is syntactically valid.  Of course, there are all sorts of issues with the code...  You take a parameter that you don't use, you declare a local variable that you don't use, the name of the procedure has no relation to what the procedure does, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try as

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE me (x IN NUMBER)
IS
    num1     NUMBER;
BEGIN
    num1 := 1;    
    insert into a (year) values(7);     
END;
/
```