# PLS-00103 error with anonymous procedure

Tags: sql, plsql, procedure

I got an error

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of
>   the following: [...]

when running an anonymous procedure (with Oracle):

```
BEGIN

DECLARE
  seq number(12);
  pk number(12);

BEGIN
  loop
      select mod_sdemol.nextval into seq from dual;
      select idn_demol into pk from demol where demol.idn_demol=seq;
      exit when pk is null;
  end loop;

INSERT INTO "T_MOD"."DEMOL" (IDN_DEMOL, COD_MOL, PATH, IND_BLOK) VALUES (seq, '13000501', 'V', 'S');

END;
```

What I am trying to do is iterate through a sequence to prevent conflicts with existing data.
According to the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967543/pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-end-of-file-when-expecting-one-of-the-follow), a PL/SQL procedure should do something with selected data, but all my SELECTs have INTOs.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need `begin` before `declare`? And where is variable `pk` is used, if it is not used why do you need a loop?

Comment: @Polppan I think the purpose of this loop is to make sure that the number generated by the sequence is not already used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the first `BEGIN`. Each `BEGIN` keyword must match an `END` keyword.